# Using JavaScript to import File Excel or CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm from Vietnam.
I'm a newbie javascript developer !
I wonder that can we import file csv and excel to database by using js ?
If i want to do this what libaries i have to use ?
Could someone help me please ?!
Thank you ! Hope you have a nice day !

Comment: Database servers will usually have a more direct way of importing data from a file/CSV. Which database are you using

Comment: You are probably depending on NodeJS, since you need a back-end language to read files from a directory and to transfer the data to a database. Lots of information can be found on the internet about how to do this, google is your friend ;) If you don't want to use NodeJS, you probably have to use another back-end language in combination with Javascript (if you would like to use JavaScript for the user interface for example)

Comment: honestly ! i use mysql in my XAMPP and i use php5 to code back-end side.